# Angular scan RFID

Tags: angular, web-applications, nfc, rfid

I have to make an application for school that has te be able to scan RFID tags from students, so they can check in before entering the class so the teachers don't have to check attendance manually.

I wondered if it's even possible for a web application to make this happen, I have done some research but couldn't find a lot of information of people who made similar applications in Angular.

Comment: For reading an RFID tag you need some hardware. This hardware needs to have an interface that allows you to get the data from the RFID tag. Typically a web application would only be used to show the results. Some (backend) application would read the tags and write the information into e.g. database. This part of the application would not be written in Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible so you have to write a backend with some SDK
The OBID4NET-SDK from [Feig](https://download.feig.de/) is a very good solution. 
This backend has to implement all your access´s by REST I consider [WebApi2](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

And your frontend with angular can call the REST-API